# I am using CLION w/ MinGW 3.2, is this ideal for C++11?

Tags: c++11, gcc, mingw, clion

**I am a student but this is a more general question and not related to any HW**

I am using CLION with MinGW 3.2 and CMake 3.2.2 Is this ideal for C++11? Or better phrased is this at minimum compatible and will not crash for most C++11 features?

A lot of my classmates are having issues compiling or getting crashes, my instructor suggested due to many of them not using the class recommended IDE (Visual Studio) and default compiler that it may be because their compiler is not C++11 compatible.

We have not used many C++11 features-in fact the only one we have used so far is **auto**. (I did some searching before and found that this was a C++11 new feature, is this correct?). Should I be worried about any compatibility issues with my given environment (MinGW 3.2 - CLION uses GCC 32 only last I checked) and CMake (ver 3.2.2)?

Also is CLION a good IDE in general? I have access to VS2013 for a year though I use a WebStorm and PyCharm for other classes and personal projects so I thought I'd stick in the JetBrains family and use CLION.

Comment: I have no idea what MinGW's versioning scheme is. What's the GCC version?

Comment: 4.9.2 ... I've been looking everywhere to see a version history of the set of compilers included in MinGW but can't find one yet. Doing "gcc --version" in my cmd gives me 4.9.2 and I am PRETTY sure this is what I have. I did install GCC through Cygwin, but later deleted that version of GCC and used MinGW. I am almost positive the MinGW version of GCC is what is returning on this call so let's hope so and assume 4.9.2

Comment: That should be OK for C++11.